# Problems with taking a video from the sd card and put them in the gridview

Tags: android, file, video, gridview, adapter

I'm having trouble taking videos from the SD card and setting it to the gridview. This is currently where i'm stuck at. My logic so far is that I'm trying to set a directory to a string array then use those values with the adapter. I also wasn't too sure about turning videos into thumbnails. What it currently does is displays a white screen. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
    public class Gridview extends Activity {

    private static final String thepath = "/sdcard/Pictures/";
    private static final File path =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(thepath);
    private static final String TAG = null;
    String[] Reelfiles;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preview);

        File directory = new File(thepath);
        directory.mkdirs();
        Reelfiles = directory.list();

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this, Reelfiles));

        }



public class  VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;

    private String[] Reelfiles;
    public VideoAdapter(Context c) {

    }

    public VideoAdapter(Context context, String[] Reelfiles) {
          this.mContext = context;
          this.Reelfiles = Reelfiles;
      }
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Reelfiles[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);


        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;

    }



        }
```

Preview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"

/>
```

My Log

```
04-03 12:18:10.079: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(14433): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
04-03 12:18:10.089: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(14433): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
04-03 12:18:10.094: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(14433): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
04-03 12:18:10.104: V/InputMethodManager(14433): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@415218b0 ic=null
04-03 12:18:10.119: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(14433): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
04-03 12:18:10.264: W/SurfaceView(14433): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
```